# Insert doubles in a cell array into a vector in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, cell

How can I take the first row of a cell array that contains doubles and insert it into a vector, without using a 'for' loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use curly braces to [get entries from the cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-117.html) as a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br2js35-1.html), then collect those values into a row vector using square brackets. Here's an example:

```
>> C = num2cell(magic(5))    %# A sample cell array

C = 

    [17]    [24]    [ 1]    [ 8]    [15]
    [23]    [ 5]    [ 7]    [14]    [16]
    [ 4]    [ 6]    [13]    [20]    [22]
    [10]    [12]    [19]    [21]    [ 3]
    [11]    [18]    [25]    [ 2]    [ 9]

>> vec = [C{1,:}]      %# Put the first row in a vector

vec =

    17    24     1     8    15
```

Comment: Both of those worked, but gnovice's was what I was trying to remember. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

```
avector = cell2mat(acellarray(1,:));
```